# Writing Console.Out to different output files

Tags: c#, stdout

Iam trying to redirect `Console.Out` to two text files using `Console.SetOut`.

```
Console.SetOut(File.CreateText("c:\\del1.txt"));
Console.WriteLine(string1);
...
Console.SetOut(File.CreateText("c:\\del2.txt"));
Console.WriteLine(string2);
```

By this redirection two text files are created with out any data. This works fine if i comment out second redirection. How can i redirect output to different files using `Console.SetOut`.

Edit1: Program terminates with out any errors, will this guarantee that all file streams are closed and flushed?

Edit2:
Thanks to every one who has replied to my question, i was able to find solution with out changing code and adding two extra lines to close the file stream.
            `Console.Out.Close();`

Can any one explain why file streams are not closed and flushed after program terminates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very bizarre scenario - IMO you should just have two different `TextWriter`, and write to *them* when you need to. Leave the console alone. If the caller wants to pipe stdout, let them worry about that via the command shell.

```
using(var file = File.CreateText(@"c:\del1.txt")) {
    file.WriteLine(string1);
}
using(var file = File.CreateText(@"c:\del2.txt")) {
    file.WriteLine(string2);
}
```

and if that means changing some existing code to pass in a `TextWriter`, then that is purely a good thing.

Comment: Yeah, I have already made those changes to use different file streams, but any idea why SetOut is failing?

Comment: i dont think it is failing, you are just not flushing the file stream, so you see nothing in the file

Comment: Have you set AutoFlush property to true as suggested?

Comment: @djeeg If the program is terminated after console writes, it takes care of closing the streams right? @Rest Wing as i am not creating any object i cannot set AutoFlush property.

Comment: System.IO.File.CreateText creates that object. Simply put it in variable (or field or property if you need to use it later again) and then set the property.

Comment: @Rest wing Thanks, it solves my purpose but it don't want to create a variable.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: See my solution, you might like  :)

Answer (score 6):

As Marc points out, you want different strings to different files. Why not just use `File.AppendAllText` for every call?

Alternative you can do something like dynamic binding by employing the `using` construct.

**update:**

A simple dynamic binding:

```
class DynamicConsole : TextWriter
{
  readonly TextWriter orig;
  readonly TextWriter output;

  public DynamicConsole(string filename)
  {
     orig = Console.Out;
    output = File.AppendText(filename);
    Console.SetOut(output);
  }

  public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
  {
    get { return output.Encoding; }
  }

  public override void Write(char value)
  {
    output.Write(value);
  }

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    Console.SetOut(orig);
    output.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Usage (nested works too):

```
Console.WriteLine("Real 1");

using (new DynamicConsole("Foo.txt"))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Moo");

  using (new DynamicConsole("Bar.txt"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Ork");
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Bar");
}

Console.WriteLine("Real 2");
```

This will print to the `Console`:

```
Real 1
Real 2
```

It will append to `Foo.txt`:

```
Moo
Bar
```

It will append to `Bar.txt`:

```
Ork
```

Comment: Very nice solution for writing to text files :).

Answer (score 2):

```
    using (TextWriter file1 = File.CreateText("c:\\del1.txt")) {
        using (TextWriter file2 = File.CreateText("c:\\del2.txt")) {
            Console.SetOut(file1);
            Console.WriteLine("test1");
            Console.SetOut(file2);
            Console.WriteLine("test2");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set **AutoFlush** property of each **System.IO.StreamWriter** returned by **System.IO.File.CreateText** to **true**.

Answer (score 2):

Move to Tracing functionality, and add the ConsoleTraceListener as one of the listeners. Then add your text files using a TextWriterTraceListener.

Use trace switches to redirect to one listener or another.

More explanation can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.traceswitch.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Modified so that you can do different strings to different files..

Could you not write a wrapper class that does this for you?

```
public class MyConsole
{
    //private List<IO.StreamWriter> m_Outputs = new List<IO.StreamWriter>();
    private Dictionary<String, IO.StreamWriter> m_Outputs = new Dictionary<String, IO.StreamWriter>();

    public MyConsole() { }
    public MyConsole(string _token, string _file)
    {
        AddOutput(_token, _file);
    }

    public void AddOutput(string _token, string _file)
    {
        IO.StreamWriter writer = new IO.StreamWriter(_file)
        m_Outputs[_token] = writer;
    }

    public void WriteLine(string _token, string _data)
    {
        if(m_Outputs.ContainsKey(_token))
            m_Outputs[_token].WriteLine(_data);
    }


    public void Close()
    {
        foreach(KeyValuePair<String, IO.StreamWriter> pair in m_Outputs)
            pair.Value.Close();
    }
} // eo class MyConsole
```

Usage:

```
MyConsole c = new MyConsole();  // or pass a file explicitly here
c.AddOutput("file1", "C:\\file1.txt");
c.AddOutput("file2", "C:\\file2.txt");
c.WriteLine("file1", "Test!");
c.WriteLine("file2", "Test2!");
```

Note this code is not tested and is written as-is, no warranty implied. :P

Comment: Note that the OP is writing different strings to the two different files, not the same string to multiple files.

Comment: this will be an overkill for what i need .

Comment: @Marc Gravell, modified to use a dictionary and have named tokens for each file, thereby facilitating this :P

Comment: Why why why? `File.AppendAllText` does this already! See my note on my answer.

Comment: @leppie, thanks for that.  I didn't know about `AppendAllText`!

Answer (score 1):

> Can any one explain why file streams
>   are not closed and flushed after
>   program terminates?

The handles to the files would eventually be released when the resource is finally disposed of. By explicitly closing the file handles, you guarantee WHEN the release happens (rather than guaranteeing THAT the release happens - it would eventually happen if you left it up to the framework).

So always close your file handles explicitly so you know you have tied up a file for the shortest amount of time possible.

Comment: sorry i should have edited my question to, why not flushed after closed.